# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code that selects an image place it in my image viewer and eventually send it via retrofit 2:

```
 public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            data?.let {
                val selectedPhotoUri = data.data
                val path = selectedPhotoUri!!.path!!.split(":")
                val filePath = path[1]
                file = File(URI(filePath))
                gView!!.iv_ier_image.setImageURI(selectedPhotoUri)
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            data?.extras?.let {
                val thumbnail: Bitmap =
                    data.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
                file = savebitmap(thumbnail)!!
                gView!!.iv_ier_image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail)
            }
        }
    }
```

Why is it when I get to the part `file = File(URI(filePath))` I get an error of:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content://media/external/images/media/41906/ORIGINAL/NONE/image/jpeg/1278296327 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list {...}} }} to activity {com.kotlin.ambulantlcs/com.kotlin.ambulantlcs.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5506)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5547)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:419)
        at com.kotlin.ambulantlcs.ui.fragments.AddIerFragment.onActivityResult(AddIerFragment.kt:212)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)
        at com.kotlin.ambulantlcs.ui.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:291)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8541)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5499)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5547) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Have you : 1. Read the [related API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.net.URI-) ; 2. Checked the value contained by `filePath` ? If so, you might want to add details in your questions, because as is, it is difficult to give you a more precise answer than what the error message already tells you : received path is not an absolute Uri (ex: `file:///storage/images`). Note, file have a more permissive constructor that takes a string as argument. But you might have to carefully think about how to manage relative paths then.

Comment: Thank you for that @amanin . I got the solution here at Stack. I just removed the `ffile = File(URI(filePath))` and just changed it to `file = File(getPath(selectedPhotoUri))`. The getPath() is the one that I got from reading solutions here at Stack.